# How to access a custom property in mock service groovy script?

Tags: groovy, soapui

Is there any way to access the *mock service* custom properties, from a *mock operation* groovy script?

Please check image, custom properties shown left bottom corner which are *mock service* properties.

[image: Please check image]

Comment: I believe that instead of custom properties, those values should come from request headers where end user can pass his details instead using fixed values from mock service side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access a *Mock service* custom property from inside the *Mock script* itself you can use the [property expansion](https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/property-expansion.html#2-Dynamic-Properties) as follows:

From the SOAPUI documentation:

> #MockService# - references a MockService property in the containing MockService

So this can do the trick:

```
context.expand('${#MockService#YourPropertyName}')
```

For you specific case:

```
def userId = context.expand('${#MockService#UserID}')
def password = context.expand('${#MockService#Password}')
```